# Batch File multiple tokens multiple variables

Tags: variables, for-loop, batch-file, token, delimiter

I am trying to read two different fields per line of a file and assign those fields to two different variables so that I can work with both of the variables together in a for loop.

Right now I have

```
for /f "tokens=6 delims=:. " %%a in ('type %1% ^| findstr /R /V "Test"') do (
echo %%a
)

for /f "tokens=12 delims=:. " %%b in ('type %1% ^| findstr /R /V "Test"') do (
echo %%b
)
```

Is there anyway to combine them into something like

```
for /f "tokens=6,12 delims=:. " %%a %%b in ('type %1% ^| findstr /R /V "Test"') do (
echo %%a
echo %%b
)
```

Because right now this statement does not work.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
for /f "tokens=6,12 delims=:. " %%a in ('type "%~1" ^| findstr /R /V "Test"') do (
  echo %%a
  echo %%b
)
```

which could be simplified to

```
for /f "tokens=6,12 delims=:. " %%a in ('findstr /V "Test" "%~1"') do (
  echo %%a
  echo %%b
)
```

since `findstr` can read from files just fine, and you're not using a regular expression anyway.